# Ошибка gray css

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://github.com/karlhorky/gray

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of
>   undefined
>       at jquery.gray.min.js:3
>       at Object. (jquery.gray.min.js:3)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 3422f88690cd0db272b1:54)
>       at Object.181 (vendor.js:4)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 3422f88690cd0db272b1:54)
>       at Object.152 (main.js:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 3422f88690cd0db272b1:54)
>       at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 3422f88690cd0db272b1:25)
>       at main.js?v=1525145897619:1

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в Modernizer'е подключенном в плагине и его устаревшей концепцией которая конфликтует с webpack. В контекст передается `this.document`, ожидая, что это будет `window.document`, но из-за того, что webpack все это ещё раз оборачивает, то соответственно внешний контекст (`this`) меняется и во внутренний уже передается `undefined`. Решением может стать [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader) + [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader).

```
npm i import-loader exports-loader -D
```

И настройками типа:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
        test: /jquery\.gray\.min\.js/,
        loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window!exports-loader?window.Modernizr'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: А куда писать данные настройки?

Comment: @StepanIvanov, в webpack.config.js

Comment: Использую сборку на gulp, вот gulpfile.js 

https://github.com/ninelines-team/ninelines-template/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Тут получается после установки несколько webpack.config.js
Вопрос в какой именно из этих файлов применить настройки

Comment: @StepanIvanov, 285 строка, только засунуть объект из `module.loaders` в `module.rules`, правда не уверен в полной совместимости данной замены.